# Getters are not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I`m trying to figure out what is getters and setters in JavaScript.
Here is my object

```
  function User(fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;

        Object.defineProperties(this,{

            firstName :{
                get: function(){
                    return this.fullName.split(" ")[0];
                },
                set :function(value){
                    this.firstName = value;
                }
            },
            lastName:{
                get: function(){
                    this.lastName = this.fullName.split(" ")[1];
                },
                set: function(value){
                    this.lastName = value;
                }
            },
            fullName :{
                set: function(value){
                    this.fullName = value;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Then creates a new user:

`var user = new User("New User");`

But when I`m trying to get the firstName property like

`alert( user.firstName )`
    it throw an error "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined".

What may cause the problem? It looks like 'this' is not visible inside get function, but as I understand it should. Thanks!

Comment: Check what this refers to in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a setter for `fullName` as direct assignment will work.

```js
function User(fullName) {
  this.fullName = fullName || '';

  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    firstName: {
      get: function() {
        return this.fullName.split(" ")[0];
      },
      set: function(value) {
        this.firstName = value; // NOTE: This will throw an error
      }
    },
    lastName: {
      get: function() {
        return this.fullName.split(" ")[1];
      },
      set: function(value) {
        this.lastName = value; // NOTE: This will throw an error
      }
    }
  });
}

var joe = new User('John Doe');
var jane = new User('Jane Dane');
jane.fullName = 'Jane Doe';
document.write(
  '<pre>' + joe.firstName + '</pre>' +
  '<pre>' + jane.lastName + '</pre>'
);
```

However, as noted in the code comments above you can't set a property on `this` to the same name as a defined property with a setter. For example:

```
// defining `firstName`
firstName: {
  ...
  set: function(value) {
    this.firstName = value; // NOTE: This will throw an error
  }
```

This operation will cause a recursion stack error as it will continuously try to update `firstName` since `this.firstName` is a setter.

To avoid this you could use local scoped variables inside the constructor function and do something like:

```js
function User(fullName) {
  var firstName;
  var lastName;

  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    firstName: {
      get: function() {
        return firstName;
      },
      set: function(value) {
        return (firstName = value);
      }
    },
    lastName: {
      get: function() {
        return lastName;
      },
      set: function(value) {
        return (lastName = value);
      }
    },
    fullName: {
      get: function() {
        return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
      },
      set: function(value) {
        var names = value && value.split(' ');
        firstName = names[0];
        lastName = names[1];
      }
    }
  });
  
  if (fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
  }
}

var joe = new User('John Doe');
var jane = new User('Jane Dane');
jane.lastName = 'Doe';
document.write(
  '<pre>' + joe.firstName + '</pre>' +
  '<pre>' + jane.lastName + '</pre>'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some issues/changes needed to your code:

1. this.fullName.split(" ")[0]; => will try to invoke the getFullName since fullName is defined as a property. Since you have not defined getFullName this results in an error
2. Say you go ahead and define a getter for fullName:

   get: function() {
       return this.fullName;
   }

   This will throw a stackoverflow since this.fullName ends up recursively calling getFullName()
3. The right way to use it would be (of course update the setters to do something useful):

```js
function User(fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    Object.defineProperties(this, {

        firstName: {
            get: function () {
                return this.fullName.split(" ")[0];
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this.firstName = value;
            }
        },
        lastName: {
            get: function () {
                return this.fullName.split(" ")[1];
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this.lastName = value;
            }
        }
    });
}
var user = new User("New User");
alert( user.firstName );
```

Comment: Setting `firstName` or `lastName` would still throw an error: `user.firstName = 'Foo';`

Answer (score 0):

fullName does not have a getter so it return undefined

**get**

A function which serves as a getter for the property, or undefined if there is no getter. The function return will be used as the value of property.

**Defaults to undefined**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description